# Google Places JS API Show Reviews

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

**JS API, not web service:**

I'm having trouble displaying the 0-5 reviews included with the Place Details Responses:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details_responses

So far I have been able to display these items:

- details.name
- details.rating
- details.open_now
- details.formatted_address
- details.types
- details.formatted_phone_number

But when I try to show **details.reviews** it just displays:

[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Has anyone had any success displaying the reviews?

```js
function createMarker(place) {
                    var image = 'img/marker.png';
                    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        icon: image,
                        position: place.geometry.location
                        });
                    var request = { reference: place.reference };

                    service.getDetails(request, function(details, status) {
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

                            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

                                // Replace empty spaces in navigation link with + symbols
                                var navLink = details.formatted_address;
                                navLink = navLink.replace(/\s/g, "+");
                                $('.navLink').html(navLink);

                                // Match Rating bar width to rating number
                                var ratingWidth = (details.rating*20)+"px";
                                $('.rating-bar > span').css('width', "'"+ratingWidth+"'");

                                var contentStr = '<h5 class="info-window-title">'+details.name+'</h5><ul class="info-window">';
                                if (!!details.rating) contentStr += '<li>Rating:&nbsp;<div class="rating-bar"><span style=width:'+ratingWidth+'></span></div><strong>'+details.rating+'</strong></li>';
                                if (!!details.open_now) contentStr += '<li class="open-now">'+details.open_now+'</li>';
                                contentStr += '<li>'+details.formatted_address+'</li>';
                                contentStr += '<li class=gray>'+details.types+'</li>';
                                // Check for platform to send appropriate app link
                                if ((navigator.platform.indexOf("iPhone") != -1)) {
                                    contentStr += '<li class="link"><a class=navLink href=http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=Current+Location&saddr='+navLink+'><i class="fa fa-automobile"></i> Get Directions</a></li>';
                                } else {
                                    contentStr += '<li class="link"><a class=navLink href=https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Current+Location/'+navLink+'><i class="fa fa-automobile"></i> Get Directions</a></li>';
                                }

                                if (!!details.formatted_phone_number) contentStr += '<li class="link"><a href="tel:'+details.formatted_phone_number+'"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> '+details.formatted_phone_number+'</a></li>';
                                if (!!details.reviews) contentStr += '<li>'+details.reviews+'</li>';
                                contentStr += '</ul>';
                                infowindow.setContent(contentStr);
                                infowindow.open(map,marker);
                            } else { 
                                var contentStr = "<h5>No Result, status="+status+"</h5>";
                                infowindow.setContent(contentStr);
                                infowindow.open(map,marker);
                            }

                        });

                    });

                }
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`details.reviews` doesn't return a string(what you get in the output is the string-representation of this array), it's an array which contains up to 5 review-objects. you must iterate over the items of this array and prepare the output on your own.

A sample-function which prepares the reviews:

```
(function (rs /*reviews-array*/ , fx /*review-parser*/ ) {
        var list = document.createElement('ul');
        rs.forEach(function (r) {
            list.appendChild(fx(r));
        });

        return '<ul>' + list.innerHTML + '</ul>';
        //remove the previous line when you want to return a DOMNode
        return list;
    }
    (details.reviews,
        function (r /*single review*/ ) {
            console.log(r.aspects)
            var item = document.createElement('li'),
                review = item.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'))
            props = {
                author_name: 'author',
                rating: 'rating',
                text: 'text'
            };
            item.appendChild(document.createElement('h6'));
            item.lastChild.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
            item.lastChild.lastChild
               .appendChild(document.createTextNode(r.author_name));
            if (r.author_url) {
                item.lastChild.lastChild.setAttribute('href', r.author_url);
            }
            item.lastChild.appendChild(document.createTextNode('(' + r.rating +
                ')'));
            if (r.aspects && r.aspects.length) {
                item.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'));
                r.aspects.forEach(function (a) {
                    item.lastChild.appendChild(document.createElement(
                        'li'));
                    item.lastChild.lastChild
                        .appendChild(document.createTextNode(a.type +
                            ':' + a.rating))
                });
            }
            item.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
            item.lastChild.appendChild(document.createTextNode(r.text));
            return item;
        }
    ))
```

---

Demo:

```js
    var map, infowindow, service;

    function initialize() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316),
        zoom: 15
      });

      var request = {
        placeId: 'ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4'
      };

      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

      service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          createMarker(place)
        }
      });
    }

    function createMarker(place) {
      var image = 'img/marker.png';
      var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        //icon: image,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });
      var request = {
        reference: place.reference
      };

      service.getDetails(request, function(details, status) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

          if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

            // Replace empty spaces in navigation link with + symbols
            var navLink = details.formatted_address;
            navLink = navLink.replace(/\s/g, "+");
            $('.navLink').html(navLink);

            // Match Rating bar width to rating number
            var ratingWidth = (details.rating * 20) + "px";
            $('.rating-bar > span').css('width', "'" + ratingWidth + "'");

            var contentStr = '<h5 class="info-window-title">' + details.name + '</h5><ul class="info-window">';
            if (!!details.rating) contentStr += '<li>Rating:&nbsp;<div class="rating-bar"><span style=width:' + ratingWidth + '></span></div><strong>' + details.rating + '</strong></li>';
            if (!!details.open_now) contentStr += '<li class="open-now">' + details.open_now + '</li>';
            contentStr += '<li>' + details.formatted_address + '</li>';
            contentStr += '<li class=gray>' + details.types + '</li>';
            // Check for platform to send appropriate app link
            if ((navigator.platform.indexOf("iPhone") != -1)) {
              contentStr += '<li class="link"><a class=navLink href=http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=Current+Location&saddr=' + navLink + '><i class="fa fa-automobile"></i> Get Directions</a></li>';
            } else {
              contentStr += '<li class="link"><a class=navLink href=https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Current+Location/' + navLink + '><i class="fa fa-automobile"></i> Get Directions</a></li>';
            }

            if (!!details.formatted_phone_number) contentStr += '<li class="link"><a href="tel:' + details.formatted_phone_number + '"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> ' + details.formatted_phone_number + '</a></li>';
            if (!!details.reviews && details.reviews.length) {

              contentStr += '<li>Reviews' +

                (function(rs /*reviews-array*/ , fx /*review-parser*/ ) {
                    var list = document.createElement('ul');
                    rs.forEach(function(r) {
                      list.appendChild(fx(r));
                    });

                    return '<ul>' + list.innerHTML + '</ul>';
                    //remove the previous line when you want to return a DOMNode
                    return list;
                  }
                  (details.reviews,
                    function(r /*single review*/ ) {
                      console.log(r.aspects)
                      var item = document.createElement('li'),
                        review = item.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'))
                      props = {
                        author_name: 'author',
                        rating: 'rating',
                        text: 'text'
                      };
                      item.appendChild(document.createElement('h6'));
                      item.lastChild.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
                      item.lastChild.lastChild
                        .appendChild(document.createTextNode(r.author_name));
                      if (r.author_url) {
                        item.lastChild.lastChild.setAttribute('href', r.author_url);
                      }
                      item.lastChild.appendChild(document.createTextNode('(' + r.rating +
                        ')'));
                      if (r.aspects && r.aspects.length) {
                        item.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'));
                        r.aspects.forEach(function(a) {
                          item.lastChild.appendChild(document.createElement(
                            'li'));
                          item.lastChild.lastChild
                            .appendChild(document.createTextNode(a.type +
                              ':' + a.rating))
                        });
                      }
                      item.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
                      item.lastChild.appendChild(document.createTextNode(r.text));
                      return item;
                    }
                  ))



              + '</li>';
            }
            contentStr += '</ul>';
            console.log(contentStr)
            infowindow.setContent(contentStr);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
          } else {
            var contentStr = "<h5>No Result, status=" + status + "</h5>";
            infowindow.setContent(contentStr);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }

        });

      });

    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you! I knew I was missing something key.