# Looping through Google Places reviews array and getting value from callback function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

I'm using the google places JavaScript API to get place details.
I am encountering two issues to do with JavaScript:

**The first is extracting user reviews from the place.reviews array**

I can get the `place.name`, `place.phone`, and `place.formatted_address` values but I am unable to retrieve the reviews from the `place.reviews` array.

I found some sample code on the link below to loop through the reviews array but I can't get it to work. I get script errors for example with the keyword `forEach`.

[Google Places JS API Show Reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29734251/google-places-js-api-show-reviews)

Is there an easy way to retrieve the values from the reviews array? 
These are the script declarations at the top of my HTML document:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<script>
```

**The Second**

I am creating a simple search app so I can view what's around me. I would like to add the distance and time from the start location to the venue the user clicks on i.e. 'London Bridge = 1 km, 10 mins'.

I can get the time and distance values using the Google matrix distance API using a callback function but I don't know how then to pass the values to the main part of my code.

I have had a look at some answers on here but I am still confused about how callback functions work:

```
function createMarkers(results, PlaceSearchStatus) {
    var resultcontent = ''; //stores place results to be displayed on map
    var resultdiv = document.getElementById('searchresults');

    if (PlaceSearchStatus == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        // if we have found something - clear map (overlays) 
        clearOverlays();
        // and create new markers by search result 
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            createMarker(results[i]);


            //use the Distance Matrix API to get the distance between this venue and start location
            /distancematrix#distance_matrix_responses
            var DistanceService = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
            var origin1 = new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById('lat').value, document.getElementById('lng').value);
            var destination1 = results[i].geometry.location;

            DistanceService.getDistanceMatrix({
                origins: [origin1],
                destinations: [destination1],
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
                avoidHighways: false,
                avoidTolls: false
            }, callback);

            function callback(response, DistanceMatrixStatus) {
                if (DistanceMatrixStatus != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
                    alert('Distance matrix API Error was: ' + DistanceMatrixStatus);
                } else {
                    var origins = response.originAddresses;
                    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;

                    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
                        var results = response.rows[i].elements;
                        //getting the distance value gives more accurate results than the text value but not using that
                        //alert(results[i].distance.value + ", " + results[i].duration.value);
                        //get the time and distance to this location from our start location
                        // Need to fix. this isn't working as this is inside a callback function.
                        var TimeAndDistance = results[i].distance.text + ", " + results[i].duration.text;
                    }
                }
            } // end of distance matrix code 

            //concatonate the accessible search results and add on the time and distance to the place name 
            resultcontent += '<p> <h2>' + '<div <input id=\"button2\" type=\"button\" class=\"button\" value=\"' + results[i].place_id + '\" onclick=\"GetIndividualPlaceDetails(this);\">' + results[i].name + '</div> </h2>';
```

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: The callbacks are asynchronous!

Answer (score 2):

The following code works for accessing the reviews and I'm using another work around for my second question:

```
len = place.reviews.length;
for (i=0; i<len; ++i) {
resultcontent += place.reviews[i].rating + ' stars';
resultcontent += ', On ' + place.reviews[i].time + ' ' + place.reviews[i].author_name + ' said:';
if (!!place.reviews[i].text)                      resultcontent += '<br />' + place.reviews[i].text;
}
}
```